# JSP provide dynamic value to JSP Tag Library

Tags: jsp, aem

I'm trying to pass a dynamic value to a jsp tag library. This is for AEM,which does a fair bit of magic, but in the end it renders its components using JSP. I tried the one in the bottom but it does nothing

```
<%
    String pagethemeclass = properties.get("pagethemeclass","");
    String clientLibName = "project.all-" + pagethemeclass;
%>
<cq:includeClientLib css=${clientLibName} />
```

I also tried an if else switch with a JSTL choose but I think the library call happens before the switch itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have it in the page context to access it in the tag libraries.

The following would work

```
<%
    String pagethemeclass = properties.get("pagethemeclass","");
    pageContext.setAttribute("clientLibName", "project.all-" + pagethemeclass);
%>
<cq:includeClientLib css="${clientLibName}" />
```

Answer (score 2):

rakhi4110 gave correct answer, but scriplets are bad style, so I would take out the scriplet block and just use jsp expression language there:

```
<cq:includeClientLib css="project.all-${properties.pagethemeclass}" />
```